# Problema con arreglo de objetos en android

Tags: android, array

```
EditText[] PNacionales;
float [] Calculo;
int x;

PNacionales = new EditText[] {
            (EditText) findViewById(R.id.PRextra),
            (EditText) findViewById(R.id.PRprimera),
            (EditText) findViewById(R.id.PRsegunda),
            (EditText) findViewById(R.id.PRtercera),
            (EditText) findViewById(R.id.PRcuarta),
            (EditText) findViewById(R.id.PRcanica)};
```

cada que se escriba que se agregue el dato del edittext al otro arreglo.

```
    for (x=0; x < PNacionales.length; x++) {
    final int index = x;
    PNacionales[x].addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
          Calculo[index] = Float.parseFloat(PNacionales[index].getText().toString());
        }
    });
}
```

> Error

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to null array
```

Lo que estoy haciendo es un arreglo de objetos de EditText es decir tengo muchos EditText y cada que se escriba en uno pasara ese valor para el otro arreglo llamado `Calculo`;

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende, ¿podrías editarla aclarando qué quieres lograr con tu código?

Comment: Añade la traza completa de la excepción NullPointerException

Comment: Inicializa el array Calculo! revisa mi respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

Con respecto al error:

> ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

El problema es obviamente al tratar de insertar un valor en un array (Calculo[x]) el cual no tiene la dimensión esperada, te recomiendo usar la misma variable del indice `x` para los 2 array.

```
 @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
              Calculo[x] = Float.parseFloat(PNacionales[x].getText().toString());
            }
```

Lo que puedes realizar es dimensionar el array `Calculo[x]` con la medida del array `PNacionales`:

```
Calculo = new float[PNacionales.size];
```

---

Si estas obteniendo el error:

> NullPointerException: Attempt to write to null array

inicializa el array:

```
 Calculo = new float[PNacionales.size];
```

ya que estas tratando de agregar un valor en un array que no tiene valor, no esta inicializado.

Answer (score 1):

Debes pasar una variable `final` que no pueda variar dentro de `afterTextChanged` para evitar que ese índice pueda variar. El error es provocado porque cuando recibes `afterTextChanged`, el valor de `x` es mayor al índice máximo, intenta acceder al item 7 cuando hay 6.

```
    for (x=0; x < PNacionales.length; x++) {
        final int index = x;
        PNacionales[x].addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
              Calculo[index] = Float.parseFloat(PNacionales[index].getText().toString());
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: error:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to null array.

Comment: Edita tu pregunta añadiendo el reporte del error. No es posible que por pasar la variable final antes reportara ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException y ahora NullPointerException, este error se producirá después, parece que hemos avanzado un paso

Comment: Listo gracias MarcGV.